# How can i make a join on datetimeindex using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

Why pandas does not let me make a join on datetimeindex?
Here is a small code block to produce the issue that i am having.

```
dti = pd.date_range('2019-01-01','2020-01-01')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dti})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dti})
df1.join(df2,on="date")
```

I tried to convert columns to datetime object first but still no luck.

```
dti = pd.date_range('2019-01-01','2020-01-01')
dto = pd.to_datetime(dti)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dto})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dto})
df1.join(df2,on="date")
```

Both of them are failing with below exception.

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known Pandas issue: [Bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27429) . Until fixed, won’t `merge` do the job:

```py
import pandas as pd

dti = pd.date_range('2019-01-01','2020-01-01')
dto = pd.to_datetime(dti)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dto})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dto})

df1.merge(df2,on="date", how='inner')
```

I believe this is a bug in Pandas. Somehow `join` behave as if one of your date is not a date data type.

Comment: It's not a bug. It's supposed to only join on the index for `other` and the index for `df2` happens to be `df2.index.dtype # dtype('int64')`. It can be a column _or_ index in the calling DataFrame, but can only be the index in the `other` `DataFrame`.

Comment: There are some examples in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html). But you're right with using `.merge()` here.  Another option would be `df1.join(df2.set_index('date'), on='date')`.